# windows service doesn't start automatically on reboot

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have made one simple service for retrieving backup from database.
I have set the start up type to "Automatic". 
The problem is when i restart the PC, that particular service doesn't start.
I have checked the Event log. It display Error message as given below:

> "Service cannot be started. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Smart_Tracker" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64..."

I have checked the Connection string in Config file of that service and it is correct.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try to log in under sa with a password from config?

Comment: If you can successfully log in try to run service using your account. ("Log on" tab in Service properties)

Comment: is your sql local onn your computer if so, you have to use delayed start

Answer (score 0):

Try to log in from SSMS using 'sa' and password defined in your configuration file. If you fail - check SQL server settings, make sure that both Windows and SQL server authentication modes are enabled (Security). If you can connect using credentials defined in configuration file, change the account under which service is running (Services->Properties->"Log on" tab). Start switching from "Local system account" to our own. Then you can change this to another user with granted privilege to log in into SQL server.